# How can we remove duplicate branch from GIT

Tags: git, github

I am new to Git , in my project they are currently using git . So i am not sure on my Name how one more duplicate branch got created , it might be by me that i am not sure .

Now I need to remove the duplicate branch which git  created which out disturbing the main branch  and the sub branch .

Any help !!!

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate branch? You can’t have two branches named the same. May you add more information to the question so we don’t need to guess?

Comment: one in upper case and one in lowercase "Swagatika" and another one is "swagatika"

Comment: Do you know how to delete a branch? If not I’d recommend reading up on the basics of git first.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-locally-and-remotely

Answer (score 2):

Newbie? First, make a backup.

```
cp -r your/repo/dir your/repo/dir.bck
```

Use

```
git branch -d branchname
```

to delete the branch with name `branchname`

You can lookup a detailed manual with

```
git branch --help
```

This will say

> -d, --delete
> Delete a branch. The branch must be fully merged in its upstream branch, or in HEAD if no upstream was set with --track or --set-upstream-to.
>
> -D  Shortcut for --delete --force.

It will also give you an example

> Delete an unneeded branch
>
> ```
>           $ git clone git://git.kernel.org/.../git.git my.git
>           $ cd my.git
>           $ git branch -d -r origin/todo origin/html origin/man   (1)
>           $ git branch -D test                                    (2)>
> ```
>
> 1. Delete the remote-tracking branches "todo", "html" and "man". The next fetch or pull will create them again unless you configure them not to. See git-fetch(1).
> 2. Delete the "test" branch even if the "master" branch (or whichever branch is currently checked out) does not have all commits from the test branch.